# is redis single threaded for n databases in single instance

Tags: redis

I heared that redis is single threaded when executing the command.
And redis instance has DB0~DB16, which can be used for different applications.

My question is that, is the redis single threaded just for single DB, or for all DBs?

e.g.
redis received query command1 for **DB1 ** and query command2 for **DB2 ** at same time,
will redis handle the query command1 and query command2 at same time?  or need to handle one by one even they are for different DBs?

Thanks.

I execpected that different DBs in single redis instance will use different threads to executing command.

I tried 'CLIENT PAUSE 30000 ALL' in DB0, and during pause period, the command sent to DB1 didn't return result until pause period ended.

Comment: Single thread for all DBs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are purely logical databases, so a single instance of `redis-server` is  single threaded for all of them.  Try and avoid using logical databases and the `SELECT` command if possible, it's generally considered an antipattern these days.